# Can I measure a Square-Root sinusoidally Waveform's Frequency Using a Digital Oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope

I have a square-root sinusoidally-varying voltage, and I would like to determine the "frequency" using my Tektronix TDS 2014C digital scope. (I understand that "frequency" is somewhat ill-defined in the case of a square-root sine - I mean the number of peaks per second).

Is there any way to do this with my scope?

Thank you!

[image: Here is a sample of what I usually refer to as a square-root sinusoidal waveform. (Channels 1 and 2).]

Comment: What is a square-root sine? can't be \$\sqrt{A\sin({\omega_0 t})}\$ because that function is imaginary half the time. Is it periodic or damped?

Comment: Can you find a way to get us a picture of the waveform?

Comment: do you mean this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWl5p1kxA_U

Comment: Sorry -- I deal with this so much that I forgot it's not exactly universal language! See Channels 1 and 2 on the image above. (For a solenoid, magnetic force goes like current squared, so I use this to get as best an approximation of a purely-sinusoidal force as possible)

Comment: This is a square root of a rectified sine and all full wave rectifiers double the frequency. The \$\sqrt{} \$ function of any positive voltage wave is the same fundamental frequency. However the nonlinear curve creates harmonics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing ill-defined about that, the frequency is 2Hz.

Perhaps it is created by a 1 Hz sinusoidal current, but it is doubled.

To read the frequency, note the period from the sweep of 250ms/division- each cycle takes 2 divisions or 500ms so the frequency is 1/0.5 = 2.0 Hz.

You can make your reading of the display a bit more accurate by looking at several cycles, or by changing the sweep to fill more divisions. At higher frequencies your Tek scope will do the calculation for you, but in this case it is too low and it just shows <10 Hz.

Comment: Well, sure, but the question is about how to read the exact frequency with the scope...

Comment: "but in this case it is too low and it just shows <10 Hz." Ok -- that's what I've been getting. Bummer that it's impossible. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you could use the FFT function (assuming it has one), and look for the fundamental, but that's a bit lazy. For more precision you might be able to use cursors and freeze the display, depending on the scope features- the manual should help.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't give enough precision. We're concerned with discrepancies between 0.005 and 0.01 Hz from the input frequency.

Comment: Can you look at the difference between a known good 2Hz and the unknown signal? Over some minutes it would slide over a portion of a cycle. Or just get ahold of a reciprocal frequency counter.